Facebook v16 graph API stopped working (08 DEC 20024)?
I am using com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:16.0.1 in android app. This is usede to fetch user friend list and send gifts or coins to there friends who are using our app.
strengly it suddenly stopped working from last two days
Has anyone had this issue and what the reason could be?
It used to work fine and could return everything, but from last 2 days something seems to have changed.
URL formed when clicked is
https://m.facebook.com/v16.0/dialog/apprequests?app_id=placeholder&data=&
display=touch&frictionless=1&
get_frictionless_recipients=1&message=You%20got%20Magic%20Portion%20from%20your%20friend&object_id=&redirect_uri=placeholder&suggestions=&title=Magic%20Portions&to=placeholder
and attaching the image too

